# How do competitive runners with asthma handle Doping tests?

Tags: running, marathon, doping

Many asthmatic medications such as pseudoefedrine (in DUACT) and different inhalers are performance-enhancing-performance drugs. I have heard cases where athletes have forgotten to inform officials that they need to use certain drugs and false alerts about doping positivity. So

**How do competitive runners with asthma handle doping tests?**

Answer (score 2):

There is the national level and the international level. IAAF has forms by which athletes can send exemption forms.

**IAAF**

1. IAAF Therapeutic Use Exemptions (TUE) Application Form [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXqNX-yc_MAhUkKsAKHadtCxQQFggyMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iaaf.org%2Fdownload%2Fdownload%3Ffilename%3D47fe93fa-3af8-4825-a659-35fa803a7331.pdf%26urlslug%3DTUE%2520Application%2520Form%25202010&usg=AFQjCNEz-6c211EZ9AjNnWpEBb4EabnDag&sig2=nVF5xsWw7E78l0SRatkSQQ)
2. [Cardiovascular evaluation of athletes - IAAF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXqNX-yc_MAhUkKsAKHadtCxQQFggnMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iaaf.org%2Fdownload%2Fdownload%3Ffilename%3D88b96d29-5bf1-40b9-8063-fa7363c94aa2.pdf%26urlslug%3DChapter%252014%253B%2520Special%2520medical%2520problems&usg=AFQjCNG8viE7tX0Db7AJtvAeCgeWmm4RbA&sig2=mSpDk4gT0PeJO-wS4IDaqw)

Comment: This has been a hot-button issue of late because the abuse of TUEs is seen as an area where athletes may be circumventing doping rules.